# PHP update rows in table

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am having some  issue here i created a script to update users account details but when the form is filled in and submit button clicked no errors come up but at the same time no changes are made in the table

THIS IS ONLY A DUMMY APPLICATION SO EVERYTHING IS KEEP BASIC

```
     <?php


session_start();


    include('connect_mysql.php');



        if(isset($_POST['update']))
        {

            $usernameNew = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]));
            $passwordNew = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]));
            $first_nameNew = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["first_name"]));
            $last_nameNew = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["last_name"]));
            $emailNew = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]));



            $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
            $editQuery = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET username='$usernameNew', password='$passwordNew', first_name='$first_nameNew', last_name='$last_nameNew' , email='$emailNew' WHERE user_id='$user_id'");


            if(!$editQuery)
            {
                echo mysql_error($editQuery);
                die($editQuery);
            }
        }

?>


<html>
<head>

<title>Edit Account</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<header><h1>E-Shop</h1></header>

    <article>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
            <h1>Edit Account</h1>

<div id="login">
    <ul id="login">
    <form method="post" name="editAccount" action="userEditAccount.php"  >
        <fieldset>  
            <legend>Fill in the form</legend>
                <label>Select Username : <input type="text" name="username" /></label>
                <label>Password : <input type="password" name="password" /></label>
                <label>Enter First Name : <input type="text" name="first_name" /></label>
                <label>Enter Last Name : <input type="text" name="last_name" /></label>
                <label>Enter E-mail Address: <input type="text" name="email" /></label>
        </fieldset>
        <br />


                <input type="submit" value="Edit Account" class="button">
<input type="hidden" name="update" value="update">


    </form>

</div>
    <form action="userhome.php" method="post">
    <div id="login">
        <ul id="login">
            <li>
                <input type="submit" value="back" onclick="index.php" class="button">   
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>      
</article>

<aside>
</aside>

<div id="footer">Text</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

SOrry for some reason the I forgotten to copy this part *faceslap*

login.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

    require('connect_mysql.php');

     if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
     {

        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        $username = stripslashes($username);
        $password = stripslashes($password);
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='$username' AND Password='$password'");
        $numrow = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($username && $password){



    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  users WHERE username='$username'");
    $numrow = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($numrow !=0){

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

            $dbusername = $row['username'];
            $dbpassword = $row['password'];         
        }

        if($username == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword ){

            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
            header("Location: userhome.php");

        }
        else{
            echo "Incorect password";
        }

    }
    else{
        die("This user dosent exists");
    }
}
else{

    $reg = die("Please enter username and password");
}
}


?>
```

Comment: where is your `PHP` code?

Comment: You haven't posted any code with an UPDATE command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't called `session_start()` at the beginning of the file, so `$username` will be an empty string, and the update command will only update rows where the username is an empty string.

Edit: In fact, that code won't even be run, because you haven't called `session_start()`, `isset($_SESSION['update'])` will evaluate to false.

Did you mean to write `$_SESSION['update']`? Shouldn't that be `$_POST['update']`?

Last but not least, personally I would replace this:

```
<input name="update" type="submit" submit="submit" value="Edit Account" class="button">
```

with this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Edit Account" class="button">
<input type="hidden" name="update" value="update">
```

At least for clarity. I don't know if it's still the case, but in time gone by not all browsers submitted the name/value of the submit button.

Comment: Done this but still no luck :/

Comment: Can you try debugging by putting in the line die($sql)? I'm curious what the SQL being executed is.

Comment: @Tomazi place `session_start()` at top of all pages and again start the flow from beginning `dologin->edit data`.

Comment: Did you mean to write if(isset($_SESSION['update']))? Shouldn't that be if(isset($_POST['update']))?

Comment: ok i made all the suggested changes and i get this ERROR now: **Notice: Undefined index: user_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\eshop\userEditAccount.php on line 22**

Comment: That means the user_id has not been set in $_SESSION global. Are you sure you logged in? And are you sure the code is correct that sets it? You should check that the code that sets that session variable is actually executed, and that session_start() is also called on that page.

Comment: You need to replace this: $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id; with this: $_SESSION['user_id'] = $dbusername;

Comment: I really do appreciate your help and involvement in my problem but once again no luck :D

Comment: Oh - in the first file you posted, you need to change the line with the SQL to: 
            $editQuery = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET username='$usernameNew', password='$passwordNew', first_name='$first_nameNew', last_name='$last_nameNew' , email='$emailNew' WHERE username='$user_id'");

Comment: again nothing :/ i spend the whole day well night trying to find out what is wrong with this script :/ and what ever i have tried it never worked there must be something wrong with the fundamentals..Wirdest thing is that no errors are outputted

Answer (score 0):

Sir from the code given above i think you have error in your login.php

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
```

You are not assigning value to $user_id that why it is setting blank value to $_SESSION['user_id'].

```
  <?php
session_start();

    require('connect_mysql.php');

     if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
     {

        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        $username = stripslashes($username);
        $password = stripslashes($password);
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='$username' AND Password='$password'");
        $numrow = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($username && $password){



    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  users WHERE username='$username'");
    $numrow = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($numrow !=0){
        $user_id = 0;  
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

            $dbusername = $row['username'];
            $dbpassword = $row['password'];         
            $user_id = $row['user_id'];
        }

        if($username == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword ){

            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
            header("Location: userhome.php");

        }
        else{
            echo "Incorect password";
        }

    }
    else{
        die("This user dosent exists");
    }
}
else{

    $reg = die("Please enter username and password");
}
}


?>
```

Comment: Your echo will look like this "UPDATE users SET username='usernameNew', password='passwordNew', first_name='first_nameNew', last_name='last_nameNew' , email='emailNew' WHERE user_id=''"   .You can see user_id is blank which explains y there is no error in query execution.